# Vigenere encryption,but keeping text file structure

Tags: java, string, encryption, substring, vigenere

```
    public static void novelEncryption() throws Exception {
    try {
           fw = new FileWriter("H:/workspace/Exercise2/src/VigenèreCipherNovel.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++) {
        char c = plaintext.charAt(i);
        if(c < 'a'|| c > 'z'){
            continue;
        }
        else if (c=='\n'){
            ciphertext = ciphertext + "\n";
        }
        res += (char) ((c + getKey().charAt(j) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a');
        j = ++j % getKey().length();
    }
    ciphertext=res;
    fw.write(ciphertext);
    fw.close();
}
```

Basically I am doing an implementation of the Vigenere Cipher and I am trying to make an encryption method.Everything works fine,but I want to keep the structure of the String ciphertext the same as the String plaintext.In other words the plaintext String I am iterating through has paragraphs and white spaces. When the encryption is done the txt file has one big String(one word).I want to keep the paragraphs and white spaces between words after encryption,but I am not sure how to do this

P.S. The String plaintext looks like this.(has spaces between words and paragraphs)

[Click to view the plain text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuGXX.png)

And I want to achieve something like this

[Click to see what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzUbE.png)

Comment: I recently added some insight to a similar problem, perhaps you can adapt the solution from Python to Java? Shouldn't be too different from what you want... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865005/whats-wrong-with-my-vigenere-cypher-encrypt-function/46865070#46865070

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with python @OliverBaumann , but I will have a look at it.

Comment: Just replace `if (c < 'a'|| c > 'z') { continue; }` and the following `else if ()` statement with `if (c < 'a'|| c > 'z') { res += c; continue; }`. However, you really should fix your code so that it can handle uppercase as well as lowercase. And please don't post or link to images of text. Just paste the text directly into your question, thanks.